# How do I forward my subdomain to my Minecraft server?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, port-forwarding, godaddy

Disclaimer: The web addresses in this question are pseudonyms.

I recently set up Minecraft server (with port forwarding) and I was using a No-IP domain for it (`foo.sytes.net`.) I purchased a domain for the server, so I didn't have use a No-IP subdomain (`minecraftserver.com`). I purchased the domain through GoDaddy.

I've attempted to set a subdomain for my site (`play.minecraftserver.com`) to forward to my No-IP site, but discovered this doesn't work. No-IP is a great service as it can check if your IP address changes, but GoDaddy can't do this, otherwise I would have simply set the subdomain to my IP and Minecraft port.

Is there a way to give myself a static IP address or use No-IP with GoDaddy so I can use a subdomain with my Minecraft server?

Comment: You can try setting up a CNAME to point play.minecraftserver.com to foo.sytes.net. It may work, and it may not work. If it doesn't work, then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a way to make your IP static, it is described in [this](https://kb.netgear.com/27476/How-to-set-a-static-IP-address-in-Windows) Netgear post.

Though before setting a static IP, you should check that the desired IP is free. You can do this by typing "arp -a" in CMD. this lists all occupied IP addresses on your network (if they are not hidden).

Comment: So when I create this static IP, will I be able to simply type, for example, 111.111.1.1:25565 as the web address for my GoDaddy subdomain?

Comment: Well the IP has to be in the same range as the default gateway, therefore if you gateway is 192.168.1.1 your up has to be 192.168.1.xxx (change xxx to desired number). REMEMBER to check it's not occupied with arp -a (in cmd)

Comment: Regarding the web address, no you won't be able to. People need your public IP to connect to your server, and this is essentially what your sub domain referees too when someone connects using a sub domain.

Comment: Couldn't edit my comment so I'm continuing here: What you made static is your internal IP, which is what I'm assuming the no-IP site is requesting (haven't messed around with no-IP sites at all)